# Pagination doesnt work in custom post type

Tags: php, pagination, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

Pagination template part includes common pagination function with style. The template part works for `archive.php` (it's for "single", you know default wp file) but doesn't work for custom post type.

Why not? How to solve it?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<main role="main">
    <!-- section -->
    <?php get_template_part( 'breadcrumb' );?>

    <!-- Inner Pages Main Section -->
    <section class="ulockd-service-details">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">

                    <?php

                    /**
                     * Setup query to show the ‘services’ post type with ‘8’ posts.
                     * Output the title with an excerpt.
                     */
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'team',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    );

                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if (have_posts()): while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    ?>

                    <?php //if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                        <?php

                        if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id() ) {
                            if ( $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg' ) )
                                ?>

                                <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                                <div class="ulockd-project-sm-thumb">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-whp" src="<?php printf( '%s', esc_url($image_src[0]) ); ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php

                        }

                        ?>

                        <div class="col-md-12 ulockd-mrgn1210">
                            <article class="ulockd-pd-content">
                                <div class="ulockd-bp-date">
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-date-innner">On <a href="#"><span class="text-thm2"><?php the_time('j'); ?></span> / <?php the_time('F Y') ?></a></li>
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-nurse-head text-thm1"></span> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></a></li>
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-chat text-thm1"></span> <?php if (comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave your thoughts', 'html5blank' ), __( '1 Comment', 'html5blank' ), __( '% Comments', 'html5blank' )); ?></a></li>
                                        <li class="ulockd-bp-comment"><a href="#"><span class="flaticon-black-check-box text-thm1"></span> <?php the_category(); ?></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?> </h3>
                                <p class="project-dp-one"><?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?></p>
                                <a class="btn btn-lg ulockd-btn-thm2" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More</a>
                            </article>
                        </div>

                        <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php else: ?>
                        <article>
                            <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
                        </article>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div></div></div></section>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question a bit. You should not add filler text when the system complains that your post is mostly code; there is a reason for that complaint -- see [ask]. Please [edit] your question and describe the problem you have. "It doesn't work" is not a helpful description. What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to include that template inside `while` loop. That's wrong.

Then, if you want to have an archive page for your `team` post type, you need to provide `'has_archive' => true` within `register_post_type()` function args.

Also, consider changing archive page default slug if needed. If you do so, you need to open `Settings > Permalinks` for resetting your permalinks structure.

Then you could either use standard `archive.php` for the whole team archive page and standard `template-parts/content.php` for one post inside the loop or rewrite either of those by creating `archive-team.php` or `content-team.php`. And `the_posts_pagination()` function will work on proper archive page (either `archive.php` or `archive-team.php`).

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things.

1. Add the argument *paged* to your wp_query args :

   ```
               $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;                   

               $args = array(
                   'post_type' => 'team',
                   'post_status' => 'publish',
                   'paged' => $paged,
                   'posts_per_page' => 1,
               );
   ```
2. Put your pagination template outside the loop :

   ```
               <?php endwhile; ?>
               <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
   ```